# create files based on directory names and create directories based on remote directories names in chef using ruby

Tags: python, ruby, bash, rubygems, chef-infra

I am new to ruby and chef. Please kindly help.
I have two scenarios here. 
I have directories recursively in chef cookbook which are inside 
     /var/chef/cache/cookbook/book_name/files/ 
        as,  " files/appname/envname/instancename/ ".
  each of these directories have some .yml files inside them with different variables and values in each of them.

1. I need to create directories first on target node/host in certain format.
2. after #1 is done, i need to create a file with certain name
    inside that newly created directory/path "
3. After the file  got created, I want to write some content into that file which will be based on the content in different yaml files located in {##/files/} of chef cookbook.

How can i achieve all the above in Chef using ruby or python? using Ruby is preferred, please. 
Please provide some sample ruby code useful in Chef for the above. Please. Highly appreciated.

Sorry if I haven't provided enough info, this is my first time writing question on here. Apologies in advance.

How can i achieve all the above in Chef using ruby or python? using Ruby is preferred, please. 
Please provide some sample ruby code useful in Chef for the above. Please. Highly appreciated.

Sorry if I haven't provided enough info, this is my first time writing question on here. Apologies in advance.

I will attach the actual question as a file since I'm having hard time figuring out how to not get errors while trying to post this question.

Adding extra info as my own comments since file attachment is not supported.

Comment: 1. I need to create directories first on target node/host as,
     /workarea/username/appname/envname/appname_envname_instancename/configuration/ -- this is how directories should look on target host.

2. after #1 is done, i need to create a file with name                        
   " appname_envname_instancename.properties "  inside that newly created directory/path " /workarea/username/appname/envname/appname_envname_instancename/configuration/ ".

Comment: 3. After the file appname_envname_instancename.properties got created, I want to write some content into that file which will be based on the content in different yaml files located in {##/files/} of chef cookbook.

Comment: sample yaml file:-
files/appname/test1.yml
    java_version: 1.8.0_172
    tomcat_version: 9.0.1

sample output of appname_envname_instancename.properties should be:-
java_version = /workarea/java/jdk1.8.0_172/
tomcat_version = /workarea/redhat/tomcat-9.0.1/